# bridging open tracing to open telemetry in go-kit

Tags: go, open-telemetry, opentracing

I am using go-kit which appears to support open tracing.

We want to use open telemetry and publish the tracing data.  I have tried to bridge these two sdk, however the exporter is not working.

There is no http listener on that port.  I cannot use just open telemetry because it is not supported by the go-kit framework.  We want to use open telemetry so I am trying to bridge the two things together

```
    exp, err := otlptracehttp.New(ctx, otlptracehttp.WithInsecure(), otlptracehttp.WithEndpoint("localhost:4318"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }


    tp := sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        sdktrace.WithSampler(sdktrace.AlwaysSample()),
    )

    bsp := sdktrace.NewSimpleSpanProcessor(exp)
    tracerProvider := sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        sdktrace.WithSampler(sdktrace.AlwaysSample()),
        sdktrace.WithSpanProcessor(bsp),
    )
    otel.SetTracerProvider(tracerProvider)

    otTracer, _ := otbridge.NewTracerPair(tp.Tracer("service"))
    stdopentracing.SetGlobalTracer(otTracer)
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing when you run your provided code? What are you expecting to see?